# Put JLabel in front of Graphics 2D Rectangle in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, panel, graphics2d

Is there any way to put the JLabel in front of the rectangle? Currently, the JLabel is underneath the rectangle.

Here is my relevant code:

```
public class MainMenu_South extends JPanel {
        MainMenu_BlueJay t; 
        JLabel start=new JLabel("START");

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.blue);
        g2d.drawRect(0, 30, 900, 30); 
        g2d.fillRect(0, 30, 900, 30);
    }

    public MainMenu_South(MainMenu_BlueJay t){

        setLayout(null);
        this.t=t;
        setBackground(Color.white);

        start.setForeground(Color.red);
        start.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));

        add(start);
        start.setBounds(100, 10, 100, 50);
        start.addMouseListener(ml);
    }

    MouseListener ml=new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {//hover
           start.setForeground(Color.white);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            start.setForeground(Color.red);
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: read the painting article referenced in the swing tag wiki :-)

Comment: and do you have some idea why this question isn't answered

Answer (score 2):

1. for better help sooner post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
2. use `paintComponent()` for Swing JComponents instead of `paint()`
3. there isn't reason to use `NullLayout`, use `LayoutManager`,
4. override `getPreferredSize` for `JPanel`, then `JFrame.pack()` will generate expected `Dimension` on the screen
5. `JLabel` is transparent, you have to `setOpaque` if you to want to dispaly `Color` as `Backgroung` in `Jlabel`
6. you have to use `repaint(last code line)` for `MouseEvents` and `Color` for `JLabel`, override MouseAdapter
7. miss any, no idea if you would need use transparency or tranclucency, or remove the JLabel