# java - Put JComponent in front of graphics in NullLayoutManager?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent

I have a JButton in a JPanel that has graphics, but the button won't show as it is in the layer BELOW the graphics.
I've already read this : [Put JLabel in front of Graphics 2D Rectangle in JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076693/put-jlabel-in-front-of-graphics-2d-rectangle-in-jpanel)

But the answers tell me not to use the NullLayoutManager.
Is there any way to do it with the NullLayoutManager, because I need to specifically position my JButton in my JPanel?
If this is not possible, are there any other ways I can position a JComponent at a position x, y? I've also googled that and NullLayoutManager is what the world wide web gives me.

Code:

```
    JPanel p = new JPanel(){

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics gr){
            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) gr;
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 800);
            g.setFont(titlefont);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.drawString("dont steal my game idea plz", 25, 100);
            g.drawImage(bi, 138, 70, null);
            repaint();
        }

    };
    p.setLayout(null);





    JButton b = new JButton("PLAY");
    b.setLocation(100, 200);
    b.setFont(ufont);




    f.add(p);
    p.add(b);
```

Comment: Every time I see `repaint()` inside of paintComponent and use of `null` layouts I get a little sick, like nails on a blackboard -- why are you doing this? Who is teaching you and many other newbies these bad habits? Please read the tutorials to see how to do this right. And read answers to similar questions from the Swing experts on this site to also see how to do things correctly. This has all been asked and answered many many times before.

Comment: *"but the button won't show as it is in the layer BELOW the graphics"* - No it's not, `paintComponent` is called BEFORE `paintChildren` which would paint the components.  The fact that you're breaking the paint chain by not calling `super.paintComponent` "might" have something to do with it

Comment: `But the answers tell me not to use the NullLayoutManager` - then why don't you try listening to the answers??? Why do you think we will change out answer just because you ask the same question again??? `because I need to specifically position my JButton in my JPanel?` - so use a layout manager to position the button. By the way there is no reason for you to paint text either. You just use a JLabel. So a layout manager will easily be able to handle both the label and button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to do it with the NullLayoutManager, because I need to specifically position my JButton in my JPanel?

The answer is "yes", but do you understand what the layout managers actually do? How they work and the role they fill in order to replace them and take over the requirements of their functionality?

`null` layouts are just a bad idea, there are so many things that can wrong with them it's mind numbing just trying to think about it. If none of the stock layout managers do what you want, maybe consider using MigLayout or some other layout manager, possibly even writing your own, at least this way, you will still be able to work within the API, which has been designed to work around layout managers.

There are a couple of other issues, first, you're painting your image AFTER the paint the text, this could cause some issues if the two overlap. Second, you're breaking the paint chain by not calling `super.paintComponent`, this could result in some unexpected and unwanted results. Third, you don't need to fill the component, use `setBackground` and let the `super.paintComponent` deal with it.

[image: Play this]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class DownWithNullLayouts {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DownWithNullLayouts();
    }

    public DownWithNullLayouts() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Font titlefont;
        private BufferedImage bi;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(30, 0, 0, 0);
            add(new JButton("Play"), gbc);
            try {
                bi = ImageIO.read(...);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            titlefont = UIManager.getFont("Label.font");
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int x = (getWidth() - bi.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight()- bi.getHeight()) / 2;
            g2d.drawImage(bi, x, y, this);
            g2d.setFont(titlefont);
            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2d.drawString("dont steal my game idea plz", 25, 100);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Take a closer look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: So it's not possible?

Comment: To do it right, you need to have a very good understanding of the role of the layout manager API, because you'll need to replace that functionality. The reason we discourage the use of null layouts generally is because don't understand what they are doing. My personal recommendation would be to write a custom layout manager which achieved the results you are looking for

Comment: Like this tutorial here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/CustomLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/DiagonalLayout.java ?

Comment: That would be a start

Comment: For some reason, the above code seems to make my JPanel's background disappear.

Comment: Nevermind, reading this seemed to help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911743/why-does-calling-dispose-on-graphics-object-cause-jpanel-to-not-render-any-com

Comment: Ah, unless you've changed my code, it should work just fine.  The use of `Graphics#dispose` in the example is required, unless you want to generate a memory leak as the first thing I do is create a copy of the `Graphics` context. I do this ALL the time when dealing with custom painting as it protects the state of the original context

Comment: Here's the thing that's scaring me, you seem to be reading up on solutions (this is a good thing) to try and solve your problem, BUT, you don't quite have enough experience or knowledge of the API to understand when a solution is a bad idea or is inappropriate for the problem you're trying to solve, this is my I've tried to steer you away from `null` layouts

Comment: OK, I've remade it to fit your code, and it is working fin now; thanks! But how would I add another button under it? I added a new button, but it puts the new button beside it.

Comment: You'd have define the `GridBagConstraints` to set the x/y properties